# Python string concatenation Idiom.  Need Clarification.

Tags: python, performance, idioms

From http://jaynes.colorado.edu/PythonIdioms.html

> "Build strings as a list and use
> ''.join at the end. join is a string
> method called on the separator, not
> the list. Calling it from the empty
> string concatenates the pieces with no
> separator, which is a Python quirk and
> rather surprising at first. This is
> important: string building with + is
> quadratic time instead of linear! If
> you learn one idiom, learn this one.
>
> Wrong: for s in strings: result += s
>
> Right: result = ''.join(strings)"

I'm not sure why this is true.  If I have some strings I want to join them, for me it isn't intuitively better to me to put them in a list then call ''.join.  Doesn't putting them into a list create some overhead?  To Clarify...

Python Command Line:

```
>>> str1 = 'Not'
>>> str2 = 'Cool'
>>> str3 = ''.join([str1, ' ', str2]) #The more efficient way **A**
>>> print str3
Not Cool
>>> str3 = str1 + ' ' + str2 #The bad way **B**
>>> print str3
Not Cool
```

Is **A** really linear time and **B** is quadratic time?

Comment: Man, ' '.join([str1, str2]), this middle space in list is really ugly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but that space is in the list to add a space when it is joined. ie. the output of yours will be 'NotCool' instead of 'Not Cool'.

Comment: That's why mkotechno suggests using `' '.join([str1,str2])` - just put the non-blank elements in the list to be joined, and join them with single blanks (the leading ' ' of the expression).

Comment: Since posting this I remember reading somewhere using + for string concatenation was optimized. Could someone who remembers the source of this information comment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. For the examples you chose the importance isn't clear because you only have two very short strings so the append would probably be faster.

But every time you do `a + b` with strings in Python it causes a new allocation and then copies all the bytes from a and b into the new string. If you do this in a loop with lots of strings these bytes have to be copied again, and again, and again and each time the amount that has to be copied gets longer. This gives the quadratic behaviour.

On the other hand, creating a list of strings doesn't copy the contents of the strings - it just copies the references. This is incredibly fast, and runs in linear time. The join method then makes just one memory allocation and copies each string into the correct position only once. This also takes only linear time.

So yes, do use the `''.join` idiom if you are potentially dealing with a large number of strings. For just two strings it doesn't matter.

If you need more convincing, try it for yourself creating a string from 10M characters:

```
>>> chars = ['a'] * 10000000
>>> r = ''
>>> for c in chars: r += c
>>> print len(r)
```

Compared with:

```
>>> chars = ['a'] * 10000000
>>> r = ''.join(chars)
>>> print len(r)
```

The first method takes about 10 seconds. The second takes under 1 second.

Answer (score 6):

Repeated concatenation is quadratic because it's [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_painter's_Algorithm) (beware that some implementations will optimize this away so that it is not quadratic). `join` avoids this because it takes the entire list of strings, allocates the necessary space and does the concatenation in one pass.

Answer (score 4):

When you code `s1 + s2`, Python needs to allocate a new string object, copy all characters of `s1` into it, then after that all characters of `s2`.  This trivial operation does not bear quadratic time costs: the cost is `O(len(s1) + len(s2))` (plus a constant for allocation, but that doesn't figure in big-O;-).

However, consider the code in the quote you're giving: `for s in strings: result += s`.

Here, *every time* a new `s` is added, *all the previous ones* have to be first copied into the newly allocated space for `result` (strings are immutable, so the new allocation and copy must take place).  Suppose you have N strings of length L: you'll copy L characters the first time, then 2 * L the second time, then 3 * L the third time... in all, that makes it `L * N * (N+1) / 2` characters getting copied... so, yep, it's quadratic in N.

In some other cases, a quadratic algorithm may be faster than a linear one for small-enough values of N (because the multipliers and constant fixed-costs may be much smaller); but that's not the case here because allocations are costly (both directly, and indirectly because of the likelihood of fragmenting memory). In comparison, the overheads of accumulating the strings into a list is essentially negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Joel writes about this in [Back to Basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious if you're referring to the same thing as other people. This optimization is important when you have *many* strings, say *M* of length *N*. Then

**A**

```
x = ''.join(strings) # Takes M*N operations
```

**B**

```
x = ''
for s in strings:
    x = x + s  # Takes N + 2*N + ... + M*N operations
```

Unless optimized away by the implementation, yes, **A** is linear in the total length `T = M*N` and **B** is `T*T / N` which is always worse and roughly quadratic if `M >> N`.

Now why it is actually quite intuitive to `join`: when you say "I have some strings" this typically can be formalized by saying that you have an *iterator* that returns strings. Now, this is exactly what you pass to `"string".join()`