# Looping and saving multiple inputs

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through a set of inputs where I ask for a user's course grade, course hours and course code. The loop keeps on repeating until the user enters "done". Once the user has entered done I want it to print out the entered courses with grade and hours.

For Example:

```
course_count = False

#LOOP through Inputs
while not course_count:

    #GET course code
    course_code = input( "Please Enter the Course Code (or done if finished): " )

    #IF course code is not equal to done (convert to lowercase)
    if course_code.lower() != "done":

        #GET course hours
        course_hours = int( input( "How many credit hours was " + course_code + "? " ) )

        #GET grade earned
        course_grade = float( input( "What grade did you earn in " + course_code + "? " ) )

    #ELSE END LOOP
    else:
        course_count = True

    print("Course: " + course_code + " Weight: " + str( course_hours ) + " hours " + "Grade: " + str( course_grade ) + "%")
```

The problem is it will always print out only one inputted course, hour and grade. How would I save more than one answer using only accumulative strings?

The output I'm looking to make is:

```
# Please Enter the Course Code (or done if finished): COMP 10001
# How many credit hours was COMP 10001? 5
# What grade did you earn in COMP 10001? 75

# Please Enter the Course Code (or done if finished): COMP 20002
# How many credit hours was COMP 10001? 8
# What grade did you earn in COMP 10001? 95

# Please Enter the Course Code (or done if finished): done

# Course: COMP 10001 Weight: 5 Grade: 75%
# Course: COMP 20002 Weight: 8 Grade: 95%
```

It's for a school practice problem and were not allowed to use lists, arrays or dictionaries if that makes sense

Comment: Add a tab before print?

Comment: @tim that wouldn't give the formatted output he is looking to create, where there is a summary provided of what information is inserted during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an output string `output_string`

Add each new line to the output string

```
...
output_string += "Course: {} Weight: {} hours Grade: {}\n".format(course_code, course_hours, course_grade"
#ELSE END LOOP
...
```

This accumulates the information into a string, using standard string formatting to insert the data from each pass through the loop.

At the end of the program, print the output string.

As others have noted, this is a pretty silly way of storing data, since accessing it, except to print out, will be difficult. Lists/dictionaries would be a lot better.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much I spent so many hours on this haha. I really do appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

See if you can relate this simplified example to your code. To get the output you describe, you need to *store* the output text somehow and access it later:

```
output_lines = []

for i in range(10):
  input_string = input("Enter some input")
  output_lines.append(input_string)

for output_line in output_lines:
  print(output_line)
```

From the comments, using only string "accumulation" (warning: quadratically bad):

```
output_text

for i in range(10):
  input_string = input("Enter some input")
  output_text = output_text + '\n' + input_string
print(output_text)
```

Note that the preferred way to build up a long string *is* to append to a list and use `'separator'.join(list_of_strings)` or print one-by-one as above.

Comment: Hey YXD, Thank you :). I do understand that but the issue is it's for a school practice problem and were not allowed to use lists/arrays/dictionaries and only string accumulation if that makes sense?

Comment: That's a pretty silly requirement IMO, but you can either print within the loop, which means your output will look a little different (try it), or declare your variable outside the loop and append to it. This is pretty bad in terms of performance - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1967732/553404 and others.

Comment: I completely agree. There is obviously a lot of easier ways to do it than this. I'll give that a try right now thank you.

Comment: It worked great. Thanks again my friend. I appreciate it more than you know.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to keep your information in a `dictionary` structure where the key is stored as the course code. Then it is as simple as iterating over each course saved in your dictionary to get the details.

**Example:**

```
course_count = False
course_info = {}
#LOOP through Inputs
while not course_count:

    #GET course code
    course_code = input( "Please Enter the Course Code (or done if finished): " )
    course_info[course_code] = {};

    #IF course code is not equal to done (convert to lowercase)
    if course_code.lower() != "done":

        #GET course hours
        course_hours = int( input( "How many credit hours was " + course_code + "? " ) )
        course_info[course_code]['hours'] = course_hours;

        #GET grade earned
        course_grade = float( input( "What grade did you earn in " + course_code + "? " ) )
        course_info[course_code]['grade'] = course_grade

    #ELSE END LOOP
    else:
        course_count = True

For course_code in course_info :
    course_hours = course_info[course_code]['hours']
    course_grade = course_info[course_code]['grade']
    print("Course: " + course_code + " Weight: " + str( course_hours ) + " hours " + "Grade: " + str( course_grade ) + "%")
```